# AJAX request not working and puzzled why, any new eyes to look at it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

This is my AJAX script which I have been using on other pages and it has worked fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form1").validate({
        debug: false,
        rules: {
            user1: "required",
            },
        messages: {
            user1: "Pick user",
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            // do other stuff for a valid form
            $.post('process.php', $("#form1").serialize(), function(data) {
                $('#result').html(data);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

My form below:

```
 <form id="form1" name="form_select"  action="process.php" method="post">

        <select size="20" name="user1" onChange="this.form.submit()">
 <options>...</option>.....
  </select>
  </form>
```

Anyone see any reason why this may not work. Been scratching my head for a decent amount of time over this one!

Comment: Why are you including jquery vatilidate twice?

Comment: What does your browser's javascript console say is the error?

Comment: Why are you making all these people ask you questions?

Comment: It's not loading into the DIV id result. That is the problem, I've amended the post.  It's been a long and late day, sorry for the minor mistakes.

Comment: Does the `result` div exist? Can you write `console.log(data);` or `alert(data);`?

Comment: The form submits correctly, but loads the file process.php into the browser, when it should load the results into the #results div.

Comment: console.log(data) in the $.post function

Comment: Are you opening this html from a "file:" URL or any other source other than "http:" or "https:"?

Comment: So, what happened? any comments? this seems like an interesting question

Answer (score 1):

Swap this.form.submit() to jQuery's submit handler

```
onChange="$(this.form).submit()"
```

You are calling the DOMs submit() function, not jQuery's submit handler, which your validate plugin is bound to.

Comment: This prevents the form submitting completely.  But I understand where your coming from.

Comment: Oh whoops, of course, it should be bound to the form, not the select. Will update answer

Comment: edit: Beated me by 8 seconds. This should do it as well `$(this.form).submit()`

Comment: Yup, it's just what OP is doing but wrapped in a jQuery object calling jQuery's `.submit()` method. +1

Comment: The form submits with your updated change, however still not into the div. Firebug says there is no XHR requests going through so somewhere something is going wrong.  This is more or less completely copied from another file where it works absolutely fine so this is why it has got me completely bamboozled.

Comment: A useful dev trick I have learned is to throw in some console.log("something") 's in your functions, to verify that they are even running. Console log everything, see if your data is coming in correctly. It is very useful for debugging.

Comment: This solution [works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/8QXAL/). And also you shouldn't include jQuery validate twice, as already commented in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I know zilch about jQuery, bur shouldn't the `submitHandler` return `false` so the form doesn't does a Web 1.0 submit?

Comment: submitHandler overrides the default submission.

Comment: I have `return false` on my submit handlers. I'll comment it to test.

Comment: The form submits correctly, but loads the file process.php into the browser, when it should load the results into the #results div.

Comment: Yes, the `submitHandler` works without returning false. The `submitHandler` replaces the standard form submit as [per documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate). Learning something new everyday.

Comment: may be the fact that you call the DOMs submit() directly, as opposed to jQuery's submit handler